# In an xpath script, how to validate absence of an HTML attribute?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

```
<div id="columnmain">
    <h3 class="toggler atStart">
      ....
    <h3 class="toggler atStart" id="H4">
      ....
    <h3 class="toggler atStart" id="H0001">
      ....
    <h3 class="toggler atStart" id="H0000">
      ....
</div>
```

while fetching the xpath value for first  from xml script I have wrote the following:

```
<children>
    <childrenExpression>
        <expression>//div[@id='columnmain']/h3[@class='toggler atStart']/a</expression>
        <href>./@href</href>
        <values>
            <report.url>./@href</report.url>
            <report.title>./text()</report.title>
        </values>
    </childrenExpression>
</children>
```

and for fetching rest  tags :

```
<children>
    <childrenExpression>
        <expression>//div[@id='columnmain']/h3[@id='H4']/a</expression>
        <href>./@href</href>
        <values>
            <report.url>./@href</report.url>
            <report.title>./text()</report.title>
        </values>
    </childrenExpression>
</children>

<children>
   <childrenExpression>
       <expression>//div[@id='columnmain']/h3[@id='H0000']/a</expression>
            <href>./@href</href>
            <values>
                <report.url>./@href</report.url>
                <report.title>./text()</report.title>
            </values>
    </childrenExpression>
</children>

<children>
   <childrenExpression>
       <expression>//div[@id='columnmain']/h3[@id='H0001']/a</expression>
            <href>./@href</href>
            <values>
                <report.url>./@href</report.url>
                <report.title>./text()</report.title>
            </values>
    </childrenExpression>
</children>
```

But when I fetch the first `<h3>` using the class name, all rest of the tags are also fetched, that is in total 4 tags are being fetched in the first case itself.
So if I want to fetch only the first tag using checking the class name and   including condition for checking the absence of id. What should I write in the `<expression>` tag.

Answer (score 3):

You can add `not(@id)` in the predicate expression for `h3` to filter out `h3` elements with `id` attribute :

```
//div[@id='columnmain']/h3[@class='toggler atStart' and not(@id)]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fn:empty`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-empty) in a predicate:

```
h3[ @class = 'toggler atStart' ][ empty(@id) ]
```

The `empty(seq)` function returns `true` if the input sequence is empty, in this case: if there is no `id` attribute

Comment: `fn:empty` is XQuery or XPath 3.0, it's likely unsupported for the OP. `not()` is the more portable alternative.